# Maximum running web worker html5 at the same

Tags: html, web-worker

Is there any maximum count of web worker that can be run at the same time?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes and no. With Web Workers, there's no hard limit but you are limited by the available CPU and memory.

There's a rather large amount of CPU and memory overhead that comes with each worker so you can bring the machine to a grind if you spin off a lot of workers.

I'd say Web Workers are best used for "long running" background tasks of 100 milliseconds or more.

Answer (score 4):

The w3c doesn't mention any limitation (see http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/)

But it depends on what you are wanting to do, the limit will be the computer on which you will run the app (be kind with your users).