# Optimal number of Web Workers

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Suppose you have a task on your webapp that demands maximum performance. The task is *highly parallelizable*: you can subdivide it on, say, 500 independent subtasks. What is the best solution?

- **(A)** Merely spawn 500 Web Workers.
- **(B)** Spawn a small amount ***t*** of Web Workers and make them consume those 500 tasks.

If ***(B)*** is the way to go, how can you determine *(empirically if needed)* the best value for ***t***? Is there any library to solve this particular problem?

Comment: keep in mind that even if the task is a "hello world", each webworker means to spawn another process and wait for another request to resolve. My notebook chokes when I have like 20 tabs open in chrome. I guess it wouldn't go much farther on webworkers

Comment: You can't spawn 500 web workers. [Firefox, for example, has a limit of 20 web workers by default.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574158/number-of-web-workers-limit)

Comment: One worker per core, otherwise you won't gain anything. Of 500 workers there would at most be N active, where N is the number of cores.

Answer (score 7):

Use [navigator.hardwareConcurrency](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorConcurrentHardware/hardwareConcurrency) for optimal number of web workers.

Browser support - http://caniuse.com/#search=hardwareConcurrency

Polyfill for non-supported browser versions - https://oswg.oftn.org/projects/core-estimator/demo/

Comment: Shouldn't the optimal number be less than `navigator.hardwareConcurrency`, as there will be many other processes running on the OS that will be competing for these threads?