# How to set a limit time for a function execution

Tags: javascript

I want to set a limit time for a function to be executed, if it can not finish its job at that time, then the function execution should be aborted. What ways I have to deal with it. I thought I would create a "setTimeout" for each function with run time, but I can not think of a way to abort the execution of the function, unless it is inside a "setTimeout" which I could give a " cleanTimeout "and abort it, but can think of other ways to do this?

> Example

Timeout:

```
const eventBus = new EventEmitter();

function Timeout(parent) {
    this.id = undefined;
    this.parent = parent;
}

Timeout.prototype.set = function(limitTimeMs) {
    const parent = this.parent;

    this.id = setTimeout(function() {
        eventBus.emit('runEnd', parent);
    }, limitTimeMs);
}

Timeout.prototype.clear = function() {
    clearTimeout(this.id);
}
```

Runner:

```
function Runner() {
  this.tests = [];
  eventBus.on('runEnd', function(test) {
    console.log('runEnd');
    // results ready for the preview layer...
  });
  eventBus.on('testEnd', function(test) {
    console.log('testEnd');
  });
}
Runner.prototype.addTest = function(test) {
  this.tests.push(test);
}
Runner.prototype.run = function() {
    for(let i = 0; i < this.tests.length; i++)
      this.tests[i].run();
}
```

Test:

```
function Test(fn, limit) {
    this.fn = fn;
    this.limit = limit;
    this.timeout = new Timeout(this);
}
Test.prototype.run = function() {
    this.fn.call(this);
    this.timeout.clear();
    eventBus.emit('testEnd', this);
}
```

Main:

```
const runner = new Runner();
const test1 = new Test(function() {
    this.timeout.set(1);  
    let i = 0;
    while(i < 1000000000)
        i++;
});
runner.addTest(test1);
runner.run();
```

> Practical Example:

http://playcode.io/197465?tabs=console&script.js&output

I've simplified the maximum, I also have to deal with "Test" asynchronous. The problem is that I can configure up to "this.timeout.set(0);" that still "fn();" is executed first, and even though it takes a long while in the "while" above, still "this.timeout.set(0);" is run after it. I understand that there is a minimum, I think "4ms" (depends on the browser) for a "setTimeout" to be called, what alternatives do I have to be able to handle it? Note that I can not modify the "fn" function, just add code before or after it.

## UP

I realized that what I was trying to do was absurd for a single thread, of course it might work, if "setTimout(0)" was executed immediately, but there would still be the problem that the test function would continue its execution, and that is a very ugly way of dealing with the problem. I found another way, because I wanted to avoid a "stackoverflow" error, so I made a move based on the **@blex** example with Web Worker, it would work, but then I thought, why do I want to avoid a "stackoverflow"? Would not that be bad? how to know if it would cause the error or not, it could be confusing, but still I continued, because I needed to know if I could do it, here it is and it works:

http://playcode.io/198133?tabs=console&index.html&output

But I thought better, I do not want to avoid a "stack exceeded" error, if it happens, it's best that I know it. So I'll deal otherwise, which is simpler, I'll pick up the initial time, then the time at the end of the test, compare the duration with the timeout, if it has exceeded, then I make a mistake. The problem, which I do not see as a problem anymore, is that the function will be executed to the end to check if the time has exceeded, and thus not being able to escape a "stack exceeded" error.

Comment: There's no built-in way to do this, since JavaScript is single-threaded and non-preemptable. The function itself would need to check periodically to see whether it has reached the time limit.

Comment: If you cannot modify said functions to check periodically if they exceeded the time limit, you might be interested in [WebWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers). They'll allow you to run code on other threads, which your main process can communicate with. If you detect that a function has run for too long, you can just do `myWorker.terminate();` and deal with it

Comment: @blex and how do I detect if a worker is delaying? anyway would not have to check periodically?

Comment: what is this function doing?

Comment: synchronous or asynchronous codes.

Comment: @PerduGames Here is an example: https://plnkr.co/edit/4UPWwOZPRRKS3TbcIjOZ?p=preview

Comment: @blex good example, make a backup for it. As for the Workers, it would be a good idea to call each function, imagine an array with many functions that has limits of execution, would it be appropriate to call a Worker for each one? What is the limit of Workers?

Comment: If you only have one or two, it won't be a problem. But there is indeed a limit _([apparently 20 by default in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32366158/1913729))_, and you'll need to find a clever way of managing them if you want to execute multiple things at once. You'll find very useful info [in this awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29422833/1913729) by [Evan Kennedy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1572938/evan-kennedy).

Comment: @blex reading the answer, I do not think it's Works I'm looking for. So how do I inspect the function every millisecond? You said you could do it too, I tried to implement it here. But I do not know how to keep checking her time.

Comment: If that function is synchronous, you cannot do anything outside of that function while it's running, it will need to check itself if it's past the time limit. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/g7rypaj3/ . If it's asynchronous, you can set a flag (a variable accessible by that function) outside of that function, and make that function check for the flag: http://jsfiddle.net/0zk178fn/

Comment: @blex there is a however, I can not add anything in the function that I want to follow the execution time, all 3 codes, their last two and the answer need to modify the function I want to follow, which I do not have access to, except for add code before or after it.

Comment: @blex I updated my question with the real simplified problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a generator to yield the execution inbetween, then check if time is over:

```
function runMax(fn, max) {
   const endAt = Date.now() + max;
   let done, iterator = fn();
   do {
     ({ done } = iterator.next());
     if(Date.now() >= endAt) return;
  } while(!done) 
}

console.log("start");
runMax(function* () {
  while(true) {
    // some long running code
    console.log("do stuff");
    // sometimes yield inbetween:
    yield;
  }
}, 1000);
console.log("aborted");
```

Comment: I updated my question with the real simplified problem.

Comment: This function is working well. Thanks.

Comment: Voted for the use of `generator`. There's a problem, though, if the "long running code" takes 10sec, we'll stop after it's done (and not after 1sec). If one wants to use this solution, he should separate the "long running code" into small-parts to allow yield in between

Answer (score 0):

```
    function someFunction() {
  // Code for your function
}

function someFunctionWithTimeout(timeout) {
  return Promise.race([
    someFunction(),
    new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
      setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('Timeout')), timeout)
    )
  ]);
}
```

In JavaScript, you can use the Promise.race() method to implement a timeout mechanism for a function call. The Promise.race() method takes an array of promises as input and returns a new promise that resolves or rejects as soon as one of the input promises resolves or rejects. You can use this method to create a promise that resolves if the function call completes within the time limit, and rejects if it takes too long.