# How much data can service worker store in browser cache per origin?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I understand service worker store all static files and dynamic data in cache memory of browser and makes a website offline. But I am curious to know that, Is there any limit of how much data service worker can store in browser cache memory per origin. Like local-storage has limit of 10 MB per origin (in most browser).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the memory limit for a service worker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35242869/what-is-the-memory-limit-for-a-service-worker)

Answer (score 3):

It's not directly service worker's cache memory - it's [Cache API's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache) storage, which currently is available only through service worker. In the future it'll be regulated by [Quota API](https://www.w3.org/TR/quota-api/).

Currently it varies between browsers. I was able to put ~500MB in Cache using service worker in Chrome and Chrome mobile, and was hitting timeout rather than exceeding any quota.

Probably it's similiar to [AppCache](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/) in relevant browsers.