# How to have an angular client to be updated before calling its corresponding API?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular-service-worker

I'm using Angular 13 as a client connecting to a .NET Core backend.

When both the backend API and the client are redeployed to the servers, how can I make sure the preexisting incompatible clients will be updated as soon as they are relaunched, or at least forced to be relaunched.

This seems a common problem to me and I have not found any guidance and/or best practices on the subject.

I've, however, found one question about [detecting that the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41854698/how-to-identify-updates-on-the-server-with-service-worker) has changed.

Should I discover it by hand or does Angular provides some tooling to do so ?

The doc states this : *In the interest of speed, the service worker doesn't wait to check for updates before it serves the application that it has cached.*

Is there a way to circumvent that ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [ServiceWorker Update Service](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-communications#swupdate-service) to check for client updates when the user open the webapp.
You can also check for client updates frequently ([link](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-communications#checking-for-updates)) if you want.

If a client update is present on the server you can [force the user to "install" it and reload the page](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-communications#forcing-update-activation).

In the angular documentation there are some example if you open the links above