# Storing base64 image stacks javascript

Tags: javascript, base64

I have a client that receives large number of base64 images from a server, and I need to display them as slider image viewer. What's the best approach to do it? Each image size is around 30kb, and there are around 200 images. Thanks!

Comment: Add an image tag with the base64 string:
`<img src="data:image/png;base64,//base64"/>`

Answer (score 1):

You can try to store either in localStorage or IndexedDB.
These links can be helpful:

- [PouchDB](https://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-with-pouchdb/) You can use it to abstract IndexedDB complexity
- [About storage and service workers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35242869/what-is-the-storage-limit-for-a-service-worker)