# Do subdomains share a cache quota?

Tags: browser-cache, service-worker

I understand -- [from the very thorough documentation out there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35242869/what-is-the-storage-limit-for-a-service-worker) -- that origins are given a certain amount of storage.

I understand that subdomains are considered to be a separate origin from the perspective of a service worker.

Does it follow that the storage quota will be independent from subdomain to subdomain? For example, will google.com and developers.google.com have separate quotas?

I'm fairly sure they will, but want to confirm.

Comment: "Service worker cache" doesn't existe: there is no cache storage dedicated for the service-workers. In fact, the service worker share the same cache with your app so there is no behavior difference in the cache quota.

Comment: Fair enough. The crux of my question remains the same, however. I will update my question title to be more generic.