# How to listen for all Quota Exceeded errors in a service worker?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, quota

I have a complex service worker setup that stores large amounts of data. In practice, that means I often run out of quota, and need to deal with this.

As far as I can tell, it seems the only way to do that is to wrap every possibly failing method with a try/catch or similar and check the error everywhere, to know when the quota has been hit. This is pretty inconvenient, requires changes throughout my code, and gets more difficult still when using modules or code from elsewhere that could also hit the quota internally.

Is there a way to listen for *all* quota exceeded errors, from any source, so I can track & handle them in one place?

Comment: Have you checked this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35242869/what-is-the-storage-limit-for-a-service-worker) about handling error scenarios?

Comment: That doesn't help sadly. It says that the error exists, but I can't see anything about how & when to catch it, let alone how to catch _all_ of them.