# PWA - empty service worker precache runtime

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, sw-precache

I'm developing an audio-based PWA and, since I'm not familiar with this technology, I have a couple of doubts regading the cache management and invalidation in the service worker.

The application need to work offline, that I covered using a SW precache.

My only doubt is the **amount of data**: in the experience there are **5 use case scenarios**. Each scenario has ~30MB of audio content, that means around 150MB + all images, js and css in total to precache.

I know that this exceeds the limit of some browsers (se this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35242869/what-is-the-storage-limit-for-a-service-worker) and this [article](https://love2dev.com/blog/what-is-the-service-worker-cache-storage-limit/#:%7E:text=Up%20to%20this%20point%20Apple,which%20equates%20to%20about%2052MB.))
and in general you must be careful with the storage size, that also depends on the user's device available space on disk.

So that's what I thought: since between one scenario and another, the users will stop by a desk with WiFi connection, my idea is to **empty the cache runtime after an user's action** (like pressing a button), and replace it with thw new content.
This way I would store only one scenario at a time, that means ~35MB, a reasonable size.

Do you think that's a good approach?
What's the best way to implement this?

Here's my current code:

`service-worker.js`

```js
 const PRECACHE = 'precache-test-v1';

 // A list of local resources we always want to be cached.
 const PRECACHE_URLS = [
   '/',
   '/audio/scenario1.mp3',
   '/audio/scenario2.mp3',
   '/audio/scenario3.mp3',
   '/audio/scenario4.mp3',
   '/audio/scenario5.mp3',
   '/css/style.css',
   '/js/bundle.js',
   '/img/favicon.png',
   '/img/logo.png',
   '/img/image1.png',
   '/img/image2.png',
   '/img/image3.png',
   '/img/image4.png',
   '/img/image5.png',
 ];

 // never cache these resources
 const TO_SKIP = [/* empty for now */];

// The install handler takes care of precaching the resources we always need.
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  const now = new Date();
  console.log(`PWA Service Worker installing - :: ${now} ::`);
  event.waitUntil(caches.open(PRECACHE).then(cache => {
    return cache.addAll(PRECACHE_URLS).then(() => {
      self.skipWaiting();
    });
  }));
});

// The activate handler takes care of cleaning up old caches.
self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
  const now = new Date();
  console.log(`PWA Service Worker activating - :: ${now} ::`);
  const currentCaches = [PRECACHE];
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
      return cacheNames.filter(cacheName => !currentCaches.includes(cacheName));
    }).then(cachesToDelete => {
      return Promise.all(cachesToDelete.map(cacheToDelete => {
        return caches.delete(cacheToDelete);
      }));
    }).then(() => self.clients.claim())
  );
});

// The fetch handler serves responses for same-origin resources from a cache.
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  // Skip cross-origin requests, like those for Google Analytics and the other provided urls.
  if (event.request.url.startsWith(self.location.origin) && TO_SKIP.every(url => !event.request.url.includes(url))) {
    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request).then(resp => {
        return resp || fetch(event.request).then(response => {
          return caches.open(PRECACHE).then(cache => {
            cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
            return response;
          });
        });
      })
    );
  }
});
```

`index.js`

```js
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
   navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(registration => {
     console.log('Registration successful, scope is:', registration.scope);
   }).catch(error => {
     console.log('Service worker registration failed, error:', error);
   });
}
```

Thank you for your time,
Francesco

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. instead of precaching 5 videos, you could provide an button `Save for offline` so that the user can save only that videos that he wants to see later offline:

```
let videoUrl = url to that video:
button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  caches.open("myVideoCache").then(function(cache) {
    fetch(videoUrl)
     .then(function(video) {
        cache.add(video);
     });
  });
});
```

Do delete 1 entry you need to open your cache and delete it. Pass the path that you stored.

```
caches.open('myVideoCache').then(function(cache) {
  cache.delete('/path/to/audio.mp4').then(function(response) {
    console.log("entry deleted");
  });
})
```

More details you can find here: https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker

Comment: Hi @Ifaruki, thanks for your answer! 
This is a good approach, but what if when the user saves the third of fourth content (is actually audio not video, but whatever) the cache size exceeds the limit?

Is there a way to target and delete the old content from the cache?

Comment: @FrancescoCretti yes you can delete single entrys from the cache, you need to pass the url of that cached asset / file.  if you use chrome, press F12. then go to applications.  then go down to cache and click on cache storage to take a look inside your `myVideoCache` or the name what you choose. then you see the row `name` and thats your URL that you need to pass at your delete method